# Add a column to empty data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to initialise a column in a data.frame look so:

```
df$newCol = 1
```

where df is a data.frame that I have defined earlier and already done some processing on.  As long as nrow(df)>0, this isn't a problem, but sometimes my data.frame has row length 0 and I get:

```
> df$newCol  = 1
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, name, value = 1) :
 1 elements in value to replace 0 elements
```

I can work around this by changing my original line to

```
df$newCol = rep(1,nrow(df))
```

but this seems a bit clumsy and is computationally prohibitive if the number of rows in df is large.  Is there a built in or standard solution to this problem?  Or should I use some custom function like so

```
addCol = function(df,name,value) {
  if(nrow(df)==0){
    df[,name] = rep(value,0)
  }else{
    df[,name] = value
  }
  df
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
df = mtcars[0, ]
df$newCol = numeric(nrow(df))
```

should be it?

This is assuming that by "row length" you mean `nrows`, in which case you need to append a vector of length 0. In such case, `numeric(nrow(df))` will give you the exact same result as `rep(0, nrow(df))`.

It also kind of assumes that you just need a new column, and not specifically column of ones - then you would simply do `+1`, which is a vectorized operation and therefore fast.

Other than that, I'm not sure you can have an "empty" column - the vector should have the same number of elements as the other vectors in the data frame. But `numeric` is fast, it should not hurt.